# Change PHP on MacOS Server, High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, osx-server, server.app, apache, php

I am using MacOS Server 5.6.1 running on a Mac Mini with High Sierra (10.13.6. 
It works completely fine and I've been hosting few Wordpress websites on it without any major troubles for couple of years now.

I wanted to try and install Magento ecommerce platform on it but it requires some specific PHP extensions hence my question.

I know how to install PHP and the extensions (via Homebrew) but I can't seem to grasp how the Apache is configured in MacOS Server as the `httpd.conf` that server seems to be using (in `/private/etc/apach2`) doesn't load any PHP module at all.

I think I saw an article on that on the web some time ago bu not able to find it anymore...

Comment: macOS Server uses webapps. There should be a site-specific configuration file in `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/`, usually named after the site it's for. Have you searched there? It's not recommended to modify other Apache config files, as they may be overwritten anytime when installing system updates.

Comment: If you want to configure it globally, maybe [this quite comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56515703/how-do-i-upgrade-php-version-in-macos-server/56611235) helps you.

Comment: Your first comment seem to nail it, I've found the `httpd_server_app.conf` in `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2` which loads the php7.so module, Changed it to my homebrew version and it works! Btw the intl extension which I was after is installed by default in the bundled php but not active. Possibly can be enabled somewhere in those config files as well, but I prefer to have same PHP version for both CLI and Apache.